The oscillatory integral $\sup_{b, z > 0} \left| \int_0^b \frac{\cos(z \sqrt{b + x}) - \cos(z \sqrt{b - x})}{x} dx \right| < \infty$
I am trying to prove the boundedness of certain oscillatory integrals and I can not deal with the following situation, which I have reduced to a specific example. I claim that
$$
\sup_{b, z > 0} \left| \int_0^b \frac{\cos(z \sqrt{b + x}) - \cos(z \sqrt{b - x})}{x} dx \right| < \infty
$$
More generally I am looking for strategies that allow us to prove
$$
\sup_{b, z > 0} \left| \int_0^b \frac{\cos(z f(b + x)) - \cos(z f(b - x))}{x} dx \right| < \infty
$$
for functions $f(x) \approx x^\alpha$, $\alpha \in (0, 1)$.
I think Van-der-Corput's lemma allows us to bound
$$
\sup_{b, z > 0} \left| \int_{\frac{1}{z}}^b \frac{\cos(z \sqrt{b \pm x})}{x} dx \right| < \infty,
$$
so the integral over $\left(0, \frac{1}{z}\right)$ is the actual hard part.
Thank you!

I have found a proof. To be rigorous, let me clarify that all singular integrals (i.e. where the integrand is not Lebesgue integrable) have to be understood as the limit as $\epsilon \searrow 0$ of the integral where an $\epsilon$-interval around the singularity is cut out.
Let me first state a version of the well-known Van-der-Corput's lemma.
Lemma 1
Let $f \in C^1((a, b); \mathbb{R})$ such that $f'$ is non-zero and monotonous. Then for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
\left| \int_a^b e^{i z f(x)} dx \right| \leq \frac{4}{|z|} \sup_{x \in (a, b)} \frac{1}{|f'(x)|}.
$$
proof: We integrate by parts:
$$
            \left| \int_a^b e^{i z f(x)} dx \right| = \left| \int_a^b \frac{1}{i z f'(x)} \frac{d}{dx} e^{i z f(x)} dx \right|
            = \left| \frac{e^{i z f(b)}}{i z f'(b)} - \frac{e^{i z f(a)}}{i z f'(a)} - \frac{1}{i z} \int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}\Bigg( \underset{\text{monotonous}}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{f'(x)}}} \Bigg) e^{i z f(x)} dx \right| \\
            \leq \frac{2}{|z|} \left( \frac{1}{|f'(b)|} + \frac{1}{|f'(a)|} \right) \leq \frac{4}{|z|} \sup_{x \in (a, b)} \frac{1}{|f'(x)|}.
$$
An easy consequence is the following Lemma.
Lemma 2
Let $f \in C^1((a, b); \mathbb{R})$ such that $f'$ is non-zero and monotonous, and let $g \in C^1((a, b); \mathbb{R})$. Then for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$
            \left| \int_a^b e^{i z f(x)} g(x) dx \right| \leq \frac{4}{|z|} \sup_{x \in (a, b)} \frac{1}{|f'(x)|} \left( \sup_{x \in (a, b)} |g(x)| + \int_a^b |g'(x)| dx \right) \,.
$$
In particular if $g$ is also monotonous, then
$$
            \left| \int_a^b e^{i z f(x)} g(x) dx \right| \leq \frac{12}{|z|} \sup_{x \in (a, b)} \frac{1}{|f'(x)|} \sup_{x \in (a, b)} |g(x)| \,.
$$
proof: We integrate by parts and use the previous lemma:
$$
            \left| \int_a^b e^{i z f(x)} g(x) dx \right| = \left| \int_a^b e^{i z f(y)} dy \, g(b) - \int_a^b \int_a^x e^{i z f(y)} dy \, g'(x) dx \right| \\
            \leq \frac{4}{|z|} \sup_{x \in (a, b)} \frac{1}{|f'(x)|} |g(b)| + \int_a^b \frac{4}{|z|} \sup_{y \in (a, x)} \frac{1}{|f'(y)|} |g'(x)| dx \\
            \leq \frac{4}{|z|} \sup_{x \in (a, b)} \frac{1}{|f'(x)|} \left( \sup_{x \in (a, b)} |g(x)| + \int_a^b |g'(x)| dx \right) .
$$
We now state and prove a general proposition that implies the claim.
Proposition 1
Let $\phi \in C^1((0, \infty); \mathbb{R})$ such that $\phi'$ is monotonous and
$$
q |x|^{\alpha - 1} \leq |\phi'(x)| \leq Q |x|^{\beta - 1}
$$
for some $1 \geq \beta > \alpha > 0$. Then
$$
\sup_{z > 0} \left| \int_0^b \frac{e^{i z \phi(b + x)} - e^{i z \phi(b - x)}}{x} dx \right| \leq \frac{24}{q 2^\alpha} + C(\beta) Q b^{\beta - \alpha}
$$
where
$$
C(\beta) = 1 + 2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{|\log(|t|)|}{(1 + t)^{1-\beta}} dt.
$$
proof: We would like to make use of the Van-der-Corput lemmas we stated above. After some experimentation we find out that this works for the regime $\left(0, \frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}\right)$. Specifically, suppose that $\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z} < b$. Then we apply Lemma 2 with $f(x) = \phi(b \pm x)$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ to obtain
$$
\left| \int_{\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}}^b \frac{e^{i z \phi(b \pm x)}}{x} dx \right| \leq \frac{12}{z} \sup_{x \in \left(\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}, b\right)} \frac{(b \pm x)^{1 - \alpha}}{q} \sup_{x \in \left(\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}, b\right)} \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{12}{z} \frac{(2 b)^{1 - \alpha}}{q} \frac{z}{b^{1-\alpha}} \leq \frac{12}{q} 2^{1 - \alpha}.
$$
To finish the case $\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z} < b$ we estimate the other half of the integral:
$$
\left| \int_0^{\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}} \frac{e^{i z \phi(x + b)} - e^{i z \phi(b - x)}}{x} dx \right|
= \left| \int_0^{\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}} \frac{1}{x} \int_{-x}^x e^{i z \phi(b + y)} i z \phi'(b + y) dy \, dx \right|
= \left| \int_{-\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}}^{\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}} e^{i z \phi(b + y)} i z \phi'(b + y) \int_{|y|}^{\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}} \frac{1}{x} dx \, dy \right|
\leq \frac{z}{b^{1-\alpha}} \int_{-\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}}^{\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z}} \frac{Q b^{1-\alpha}}{(b + y)^{1-\beta}} \left|\log\left(\frac{b^{1-\alpha}}{z} \frac{1}{|y|}\right)\right| dy
= b^{\beta - \alpha} \int_{-1}^0 \frac{Q}{\left(1 + \frac{t}{b^\alpha z}\right)^{1-\beta}} \left|\log\left(\frac{1}{|t|}\right)\right| dt + b^{\beta - \alpha} \int_0^1 \frac{Q}{\left(1 + \frac{t}{b^\alpha z}\right)^{1-\beta}} \left|\log\left(\frac{1}{|t|}\right)\right| dt \\
\leq b^{\beta - \alpha} \int_{-1}^0 \frac{Q}{(1 + t)^{1-\beta}} \left|\log\left(\frac{1}{|t|}\right)\right| dt + b^{\beta - \alpha} \int_0^1 Q \left|\log\left(\frac{1}{|t|}\right)\right| dt \leq C_1(\beta) Q b^{\beta - \alpha}.
$$
Note that at the end we have used $b^\alpha z > 1$.
It remains to deal with the case $b^\alpha z \leq 1$. Here we start similarly to before but then estimate $z \leq \frac{1}{b^\alpha}$:
$$
\left| \int_0^b \frac{e^{i z \phi(b + x)} - e^{i z \phi(b - x)}}{x} dx \right|
= \left| \int_{-b}^b e^{i z \phi(b + y)} i z \phi'(b + y) \int_{|y|}^b \frac{1}{x} dx \, dy \right| \\
\leq \int_{-b}^b \frac{Q}{2 b^\alpha (b + y)^{1-\beta}} \left|\log\left(\frac{b}{|y|}\right)\right| dy
= b^{\beta - \alpha} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{Q}{(1 + t)^{1-\beta}} \left|\log\left(\frac{1}{|t|}\right)\right| dt \leq C_2(\beta) Q b^{\beta - \alpha}.
$$

Here is a computer based proof done with Mathematica 14.0.
NMaximize[{RealAbs[NIntegrate[(Cos[z*Sqrt[b + x]] - Cos[z*Sqrt[b - x]])/x, {x, 0, 
 b}]], b > 0 && z > 0}, {b, z}]


{3.44336, {b -> 4.74485, z -> 3.60809}}

Addition. The command of Maple
DirectSearch:-Search(abs(evalf(Int((cos(z*sqrt(b+x))-cos(z*sqrt(b-x)))/x, x = 0 .. b))), {b >= 0, z >= 0}, maximize);


[3.44335637288522, [b = 4.80999876514844, z = 3.58357016798085], 109]

confirms the above result.

Can you elaborate on how Mathematica does this? I guess it calculates derivatives with respect to b and z and then finds the global maximum as a critical point (numerically)?

No, this is not so. The optimal solution is not unique, as NMaximize[{RealAbs[    NIntegrate[(Cos[z*Sqrt[b + x]] - Cos[z*Sqrt[b - x]])/x, {x, 0,       b}]], b > 0 && z > 0}, {b, z},   Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", "SearchPoints" -> 100}], resulting in {3.44336, {b -> 3.7667, z -> 4.04956}}, shows. The algorithm is described in the documentation.

$$I=\int_0^b \frac{\cos(z \sqrt{b + x}) - \cos(z \sqrt{b - x})}{x}\,dx $$
Let $x=bt$ and $k=z \sqrt b$ to make
$$I=\int_0^1  \frac{\cos \left(k \sqrt{1+t}\right)-\cos \left(k
   \sqrt{1-t}\right)}{t}\, dt$$ which converge.
$$I_1=\int\frac{\cos \left(k \sqrt{1+t}\right)}{t}\,dt=\cos (k) \left(\text{Ci}\left(k-k
   \sqrt{t+1}\right)+\text{Ci}\left(k\sqrt{1+t} +k\right)\right)+$$ $$\sin (k) \left(\text{Si}\left(k-k
   \sqrt{t+1}\right)+\text{Si}\left(k\sqrt{t+1}+k\right)\right)$$
$$I_2=\int\frac{\cos \left(k \sqrt{1-t}\right)}{t}\,dt=\cos (k) \left(\text{Ci}\left(k-k
   \sqrt{1-t}\right)+\text{Ci}\left(k\sqrt{1-t} +k\right)\right)+$$
$$\sin (k) \left(\text{Si}\left(k-k
   \sqrt{1-t}\right)+\text{Si}\left(k\sqrt{1-t} +k\right)\right)$$
The problem is at the lower bound where we face an Indeterminate form. Expandina as series around $t=0$, the value at the lower bound is $i\pi \cos(k)+O(t)$.
So
$$I=\left(\text{Ci}\left(k-\sqrt{2}
   k\right)+\text{Ci}\left(\sqrt{2} k+k\right)-2 \text{Ci}(k)-i \pi \right) \cos
   (k)+$$
$$\left(\text{Si}\left(k-\sqrt{2}
   k\right)+\text{Si}\left(\sqrt{2} k+k\right)-2 \text{Si}(k)\right) \sin (k)$$
Numerically, the derivative of $I$ with respect to $k$ cancels around
$$\{2.07975,4.91218,10.8914,14.0888,17.3341,20.4708,23.5482,\cdots\}$$ and
$$-3.44336 \leq I \leq  3.25405 \quad \implies \quad |I| \leq3.44336  $$ the minimum value corresponding to $k=7.85938$ and the maximum value to $k=10.8914$. This corresponds exactly to @user64494 result.
Remark
The asymptotic of $I$ is
$$I =-\pi  \sin (k)+2 \sqrt{2}\,\frac{ \sin \left(k\sqrt{2} \right)}{k}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)$$
This simple expression would give, as an approximation,
$$-3.50084 \leq I \leq  3.43417$$

We have (cf. Claude Leibovici's result)
\begin{align*}
 &\sup_{b, z > 0} \left| \int_0^b \frac{\cos(z \sqrt{b + x}) - \cos(z \sqrt{b - x})}{x} \mathrm{d} x \right|\\
 ={}& \sup_{b, z > 0} \left| \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(z\sqrt{b} \sqrt{1 + y}) - \cos(z\sqrt{b} \sqrt{1 - y})}{y} \mathrm{d} y \right|\\
 ={}& \sup_{c > 0} \left| \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(c \sqrt{1 + y}) - \cos(c \sqrt{1 - y})}{y} \mathrm{d} y \right|\\
 ={}& \sup_{c > 0} \left| \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(c \sqrt{1 + y}) - \cos c}{y} \mathrm{d} y +  \int_0^1 \frac{\cos c - \cos(c \sqrt{1 - y})}{y} \mathrm{d} y\right|.
\end{align*}
We have (via Maple - a computer algebra system (CAS))
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(c \sqrt{1 + y}) - \cos c}{y} \mathrm{d} y\\
 ={}& [\mathrm{Ci}(c\sqrt{2} - c) + \mathrm{Ci}(c\sqrt{2} + c) - \gamma + \ln{2} - \ln c - \mathrm{Ci}(2c)]\cos c \\
 &\qquad + [\mathrm{Si}(c\sqrt{2} + c) - \mathrm{Si}(c\sqrt{2} - c) - \mathrm{Si}(2c)]\sin c,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^1 \frac{\cos c - \cos(c \sqrt{1 - y})}{y} \mathrm{d} y\\
 ={}& [-2\mathrm{Ci}(c) + \gamma + \mathrm{Ci}(2c) - \ln{2} + \ln{c}]\cos c  + [-2\mathrm{Si}(c) + \mathrm{Si}(2c)]\sin c
\end{align*}
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni  constant. Then we have
\begin{align*}
 &\int_0^1 \frac{\cos(c \sqrt{1 + y}) - \cos c}{y} \mathrm{d} y +  \int_0^1 \frac{\cos c - \cos(c \sqrt{1 - y})}{y} \mathrm{d} y \\
 ={}& [\mathrm{Ci}(c\sqrt{2} - c) + \mathrm{Ci}(c\sqrt{2} + c) - 2\mathrm{Ci}(c)]\cos c\\
 &\qquad + [\mathrm{Si}(c\sqrt{2} + c) - \mathrm{Si}(c\sqrt{2} - c) - 2\mathrm{Si}(c)]\sin c.
\end{align*}
We have
\begin{align*}
 &\left|\mathrm{Ci}(c\sqrt{2} - c) + \mathrm{Ci}(c\sqrt{2} + c) - 2\mathrm{Ci}(c)\right|\\
 ={}& \left|\int_{c\sqrt{2} - c}^c \frac{1 - \cos t}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t - \int_c^{c\sqrt{2} + c} \frac{1 - \cos t}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t\right|\\
 ={}& \left|\int_{\sqrt{2} - 1}^1 \frac{1 - \cos ct}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t - \int_1^{\sqrt{2} + 1} \frac{1 - \cos ct}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t\right|\\
 \le{}& \int_{\sqrt{2} - 1}^1 \frac{1 - \cos ct}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t + \int_1^{\sqrt{2} + 1} \frac{1 - \cos ct}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t\\
 \le{}& \int_{\sqrt{2} - 1}^1 \frac{2}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t + \int_1^{\sqrt{2} + 1} \frac{2}{t}\,\mathrm{d} t\\
 ={}& 4\ln(1 + \sqrt{2}).
\end{align*}
Also, $\mathrm{Si}(u)$ is uniformly bounded on $[0, \infty)$.
Thus,
$$\sup_{c > 0} \left| \int_0^1 \frac{\cos(c \sqrt{1 + y}) - \cos c}{y} \mathrm{d} y +  \int_0^1 \frac{\cos c - \cos(c \sqrt{1 - y})}{y} \mathrm{d} y\right| < \infty.$$
